Preferred use of unique ptr, shared ptr and reference in ROS2?
When using ROS2 and browsing available existing repo's, I have come across multiple standards. And I was wondering, is there a ROS2 preferred way. For the following three example cases:

Message callbacks, most of them seem to be using shared ptrs, but why not a unique one's. Ownership often does not seem to be shared over multiple threads.
Filling out e.g. the header as part of a larger message, in a seperate function. Should one have an in my opinion less logical shared pointer which then needs to be dereferenced or a return by value function. Or is a unique pointer with move more efficient or even preferred?


auto header = Msg::SharedPtr HeaderConstructor(); // Followed by BigMsg->header = (*header);
auto header = Msg HeaderConstructor(); // Followed by BigMsg->header = (header);


When publishing I often see messages constructed as auto msg = std::make_shared<msg>(), even though it has to be published eventually as publisher->publish(*msg);. What is the use of seemingly unnecessary extra step?



When publishing I often see messages constructed as auto msg = std::make_shared(), even though it has to be published eventually as publisher->publish(*msg);. What is the use of seemingly unnecessary extra step?

IMO, this is bad practice. You should virtually always publish and subscribe using smart pointers, but you should give ownership to the middleware over them rather than publishing objects. Publishing and subscribing to smart pointers makes IPC zero-copy possible by removing a copy to populate a smart pointer internally. It also removes some performance jitter.
If you look across the  board in Nav2, you'll see we exclusively publish and subscribe to smart pointers (except in unit tests).
For example:
publisher->publish(std::move(std::shared_ptr<MyMsg>()));

(where obviously you'd create and populate your message before this line, but just want a complete example line)


Filling out e.g. the header as part of a larger message, in a seperate function.

I don't think its preferred or not preferred. That appears to be the preference of who ever code it is that you are reading :-) I suppose it can reduce boilerplate if you're populating alot of messages with headers. I wouldn't read too much into this.

Thanks for the clarification! Is the "publish as shared pointer" something which was removed in recent releases?Looking at the ros2/rclpp source code, I can find it in the bouncy release [link]https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/1869b84a0ca60f758f63f6374b641a5bd93c3fca/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/publisher.hpp#L218 but not in e.g. the humble release, there I only find a reference of the message or a unique pointer being published. Is there any reason for this removal of shared ptr publishing?

I looked at the internals, it looks like the unique pointer is converted into a shared pointer without copy when/if necessary to do IPC communication. You can think of it that rclcpp is handling itself internally
